# Make Elasticsearch return the number of all documents on query

Tags: elasticsearch

When I do a query Elasticsearch returns how many hits I get. Can I also get it to reply how many documents it has in total?
Here I've added the imaginary field **sum_documents** to the result. Does such thing exist, or to I have to make an extra query to fetch the sum?

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "sum_documents": 500,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [`global` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html) in your query, and it will return the total document count in your search context (index/alias + type(s))

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "viking",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "harvester-test": {
      "global": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val. Thanks for the suggestion. I could not get it working, though. Would you mind having a look? I've updated the post with the query I tried.

Comment: I've updated my answer. `aggs` should be at the top level, i.e. at the same level as the `query` part.